# Webpage not available - The webpage at com.googlecontent.apps... could not be loaded because ERR_UNKNOWN_URL_SCHEME

Tags: angular, nativescript, google-oauth

I'm having some issue using oauth-2 by google with nativescript-angular. At the start the code is

```
public onTapLogin() {
    console.log("I'm in onTapLogin");
    this.authService
        .tnsOauthLogin("google")
        .then((result: ITnsOAuthTokenResult) => {
          console.log("back to login component with token " + result.accessToken);
          this.routerExtensions
              .navigate(["../register"])
              .then(() => console.log("navigated to /authenticated"))
              .catch(err => console.log("error navigating to /authenticated: " + err));
        })
        .catch(e => console.log("Error: " + e));
    this.authService.tnsRefreshOAuthAccessToken()
  }

}
```

onTapLogin is called and then tnsOAuthLogin is called.

```
  public tnsOauthLogin(providerType): Promise<ITnsOAuthTokenResult> {
    this.client = new TnsOAuthClient(providerType);
    console.log('im in authservice.tnsoauthlogin ')
    return new Promise<ITnsOAuthTokenResult>((resolve, reject) => {
      console.log('im just calling loginWithCompletion')
      this.client.loginWithCompletion(
        (tokenResult: ITnsOAuthTokenResult, error) => {
          if (error) {
            console.error("back to main page with error: ");
            console.error(error);
            reject(error);
          } else {
            console.log("back to main page with access token: ");
            console.log(tokenResult);
            resolve(tokenResult);
          }
        }
      );
    });
  }
```

After that loginWithCompletion is called I receive the error described at the title. The last log that I receive is 'im just calling loginWithCompletion'. After that nothing else.

I also registered clientId and the other settings before calling bootstrap

```
export function configureOAuthProviders(){
  console.log('caalling configure oauthProvider');
  const googleProvider = configureOAuthProviderGoogle();

  configureTnsOAuth([googleProvider]);
}

export function configureOAuthProviderGoogle(): TnsOaProvider{

  const googleProviderOptions: TnsOaProviderOptionsGoogle={
    openIdSupport:"oid-full",
    clientId:"********************",
    redirectUri:"*****************:/auth",
    urlScheme:"********************",
    scopes:["email"]
  };

  const googleProvider = new TnsOaProviderGoogle(googleProviderOptions);

    return googleProvider;
  }
```

Finally here is my AndroidManifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="__PACKAGE__"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0">

    <supports-screens
        android:smallScreens="true"
        android:normalScreens="true"
        android:largeScreens="true"
        android:xlargeScreens="true"/>

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="17"
        android:targetSdkVersion="__APILEVEL__"/>

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>

    <application
        android:name="com.tns.NativeScriptApplication"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/icon"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

        <activity
            android:name="com.tns.NativeScriptActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_kimera"
            android:launchMode="singleTask"
            android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|screenLayout|locale|uiMode"
            android:theme="@style/LaunchScreenTheme">

            <meta-data android:name="SET_THEME_ON_LAUNCH" android:resource="@style/AppTheme" />

            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>

            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />

                <data android:scheme="***********"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name="com.tns.ErrorReportActivity"/>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

in which android:scheme has the same url of urlscheme setting.

Do someone have a clue for that issue? Any suggestion would be appreciated.

I have tried putting my Oauth google settings in the sample that nativescript provides us by alex ziskind and it seems working fine

Comment: Are you using `Chrome` on your Android for authentication? Whats your Android version?

Comment: I use genymotion with samsung galaxy s6 5.1 - API22 emulator. Also I use the default browser installed, that works using demo angular project downloaded from nativescript.docs.  Finally I tried oAuth using Facebook and it's working. So I think the issue could be the wrong redirectUri or another settings (although I received them from google oAuthId setup)

Comment: If you just palace the URL in an anchor tag and click on it, does it open your app?